# Float multiple css divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible at all that the pink (link3/link4) div can start at the same top position like the div(link1/link2) ?

Or do I still need a wrapper div for the left buttonbar and Treediv and another for the right buttonbar + datagriddiv ?

[image]

**CSS**

```
html 
{
    background-color:Yellow;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%; 
}

body {
    background-color:Green;    
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
}

a:link, a:visited, 
a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}

#TreeWrapper{
   background-color:Aqua; 
   float:left;
    width:200px; 
    height:100%; 
    overflow:auto;     
}

#DataGridWrapper{
     background-color:Silver;
     height:100%;    
     overflow:auto; 
}

.clear
{
    clear:left;    
}

#DataGridButtonBar
{
    background-color:Fuchsia;   


}

#TreeButtonBar
{  
    width:200px;
    background-color:Maroon;    
}
```

**HTML**:

```
 <div id="TreeButtonBar">
        @Html.ActionLink("link1", "AddNode")
        @Html.ActionLink("link2", "DeleteNode")
    </div>    

    <div id="TreeWrapper">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
    </div>

    <div id="DataGridButtonBar">
        @Html.ActionLink("link3", "AddTeststep")
        @Html.ActionLink("link4", "DeleteTeststep")
    </div>

    <div id="DataGridWrapper">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
    </div>


<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just put a DIV wrapper around #TreeButtonBar and #TreeWrapper and float it left?

Or, instead can you change the order of your DIVs slightly and use rows.

```
<div>
<div id="TreeButtonBar"></div>
<div id="DataGridButtonBar"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div id="TreeWrapper"></div>
<div id="DataGridWrapper"></div>
</div>
```

These are just a couple of ways I could think of to do what you want. Have you tried these or something similar already?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/64/ why does the DataGridWrapper not float to the right side ? and why does the DataGridButtonBar goes under the TreeButtonBar when I resize my window smaller horizontally?

Comment: from WWW: "First of all, if you want it to be 100 percent wide, don't float it." That is exactly my problem and now it works. http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/68/

Comment: TABLEs might work even better for you if you only need basic layouts. I don't usually suggest them but programmers love TABLEs and they tend to cut down on the amount of CSS you have to use.

Comment: do you know why the pink datagridbuttonbar div breaks... under the left treebuttonbar when I resize the window and the text/links within the datagridbuttonbar has no space anymore for the content?

Comment: The pink DIV breaks because the content needs to go somewhere. It goes under #TreeButtonBar because #TreeButtonBar has `float:left`. If you try using a TABLE, with the heights/widths you need you will struggle less with these odd CSS behaviors. If you still want to use DIVs, I would suggest looking into `display:inline-block` in place of using `float:left` since it places your contents into boxes instead of liquid wrappers so it might be easier to work with.

Comment: "...the content needs to go somewhere" well why is the DataGridButtonBar`s height not grow vertically so that the buttons would line-break instead of the present behavior? That would be much better.

Comment: ...there's a style for what you are describing display:inline-block instead of float:left. You could make another Stack Overflow question with your last comment and probably get some good answers. It really comes down to what I said in my last comment though. I would use inline-block instead of float:left but it depends what you want to do and why you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/

Make sure you expand the result panel in the fiddle.

**edit:** in that solution you don't have to use any wrappers.

Comment: I edited it but there is still a width problem with the datagrid toolbar div: http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/7/

Comment: Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/8/

That problem occurred because the datagrid div was not floated to the left. Please tell me if you got the desired result in that fiddle.

Comment: no it does ot work at all. http://jsfiddle.net/T38Tn/11/ I want to have width 100% for the DataGrid button bar and the DataGrid itself but then the float does not work?